# How do I manage xen-hypervisor using virt-manager client?

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, xen

I've installed xen-hypervisor 4.11 on my debian 10 desktop. But, when I add xen connection to my virt-manager it shows this error.

```
Unable to connect to libvirt xen:///.

Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': Connection refused

Verify that:
 - A Xen host kernel was booted
 - The Xen service has been started

Libvirt URI is: xen:///

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 1012, in _do_open
    self._backend.open(connectauth.creds_dialog, self)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/connection.py", line 138, in open
    open_flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 104, in openAuth
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virConnectOpenAuth() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': Connection refused
```

Do I need a IOMMU compatible motherboard to use Xen-hypervisor? or something else?

Answer (score 1):

1. Install libvirt-daemon-driver-xen
2. Restart libvirtd service